# OnTouch method in OnDraw

Tags: android, touch-event, ondraw

I need to set an onTouch method to the rect that I have set up but I dont know how to do this in an OnDraw method. this but I dont know how here my code, Thanks for the help!

```
public class Tab3 extends View implements OnTouchListener
{
    int x1, x2, y1, y2;
    Rect Rect = new Rect();
    public Tab3(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super (context, attrs);
        x1 = 0;
        x2 = 100;
        y1 = 0;
        y2 = 100;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        Rect.set(x1, y1, x2, y2);

        Paint blue = new Paint();
        blue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawRect(Rect, blue);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can have a lot of problems with

```
Rect Rect = new Rect();
```

name it

```
Rect rect2 = new Rect();
```

or something like that and not Rect Rect

A small performence tipp

```
Rect.set(x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

make this in the

```
public Tab3(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
}
```

because the

```
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
```

is called every time you make a repaint with

```
invalidate();
```

her you check if you press in the rect

```
if (rect2.contains(event.getX(),event.getY())) {
```

Comment: when I do this line of code  `if rect2.contains(event.getX()event.getY())) {` i get an error on "contains" saying "if (rect2.contains(event.getX()event.getY())) {" what was my mistake?

Comment: you have to cast them to int
if (rect2.contains((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY())) {

Answer (score 2):

in your onTouch just put :

```
if(Rect.contains((int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY())){
```

i think this is what your asking let me know if its not

Comment: I think that this is what I want/ need but its not working, im not getting any erros or anything but when I run it nothing happens.. this is what I have `x1 = 0;
  x2 = 300;    
  y1 = 0;
  y2 = 300; 
@Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
 {
  if (rect2.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY()))
  {
   Log.d("TouchView", "On Touched");
   x2 = 100;
   y2 = 100;
  }
  return true;
 }`

Comment: Oh yeah and in the onDraw I have `rect2.set(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  
  Paint blue = new Paint();
  blue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
  canvas.drawRect(rect2, blue);

  invalidate();`

Comment: hmm in your constructor for the class do you have               setFocusable(true);
  setFocusableInTouchMode(true) ;
  setOnTouchListener(this); i dont think all of those are required i think just the last two but put all of them to be safe
  requestFocus();

Answer (score 0):

Read about the MotionEvent class.

Answer (score 0):

in `onTouch`, you can do the following things:

```
if(Rect.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())) {
//do something
}
return super.onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event);  //call super's method so that system would send event to you only once when you touched it.
```

Comment: Im not sure how the `return super.onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event);` is supost to work because I just get a bunch of errors when I put that in and with the if statment and I put somthing in there nothing happens.